# How can I make a button print in the display I created? (Tkinter)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have been working on an app in python for a teacher at my school. What I want it to do is have a simple GUI and a way I can type in a word and it will print the words value in the same slot i typed the word.(kind of like a calculator) A=1 B=2 C=3 etc. It is fairly simple, as i am a beginner, but I can't quite get my button to show the value of the words I type in. If anyone could help it would be great!
Thanks!
Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys

def dollaramount():
    print sum(map(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".index, raw_input().lower()))


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
num1=StringVar()

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side=TOP)

txtDisplay=Entry(frame, textvariable = num1, bd= 20, insertwidth= 1, font= 30, bg="white", fg="black")
txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

button1 = Button(topframe, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, text="=", bg="white", fg="black", command=dollaramount)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys

def dollaramount():
    # get the word written in the entry
    word = num1.get()
    # compute its value
    val = sum(map(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".index, word.lower()))
    # display its value in the entry
    num1.set("%s=%i" % (word, val))

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
num1=StringVar(root)

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side=TOP)

txtDisplay=Entry(frame, textvariable = num1, bd= 20, insertwidth= 1, font= 30, bg="white", fg="black")
txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

button1 = Button(topframe, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, text="=", bg="white", fg="black", command=dollaramount)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Your `dollaramount` function was not working because you used command line specific functions `print` and `raw_input` instead of using the `set` and `get` methods of the StringVar. I commented the code so that you can understand what it does.